# Django-python-Arduino Check Device Connection?

Tags: python, django, arduino

I am working on Django with Arduino. I used the pyserial package to connect to arduino. I want to blink the led on button click and stop blinking on another button called stop. But there are errors in connection.

The Django code I wrote works once but when I disconnect and connect the usb again it doesn't work giving ' WriteFailed' error. My Django code looks like this:

```
ser = serial.Serial('COM3', 9600, timeout=0)

def blink(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        key = request.POST.get('key').encode('ascii')
        ser.write(key)
```

I made it work in python but don't know how to make it respond on Django web app. Rest of my code looks like this:

```
import serial

while 1:
    try:
        ser = serial.Serial('COM3', 9600, timeout=0)
        while 1:
            var = raw_input("Enter 0 or 1 to control led: ")
            ser.write(var)
    except:
        print("not connected")
```

I want to show an error " device not connected " if the usb is not plugged in and if it is then it should respond on button click.